# Слияние веток в Git-e

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Работаю над проектом, на данный момент есть ответвление от ветки `master` - ветка `Issue 2`. Я решил свой issue в ветке `Issue 2` и сделал `Pull Request`. Мержить в `master`, пока не заревьювают `Issue 2` я не могу. Но времени ждать нету и нужно приступать к решению `Issue 3`. Вопрос, как правильно в данном случае мне поступить, что бы начать работу над `Issue 3`? Правильно было бы сделать ответвление от `Issue 2` - `Issue 3 temp`. Работать над `Issue 3 tmp`. Затем, когда заревьювают `Issue 2` и я могу её слить в `master`. Создать ответвление от ветки `master` - `Issue 3` и слить в неё свои наработки из `Issue 3 tmp`. Правильно ли это в теории, да и технически, возможно ли?

Comment: надо дать вопросу какой-нибудь более информативный заголовок.

Comment: Ответвляться  от *master*, потом решать конфликты. Если проблемы зависимые, то ответвляетесь от предыдущей ветки и потом сделаете у себя *rebase* на обновлённый *master*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вариантов, конечно, очень много.

если `issue3` никак не зависит от `issue2`, то смело делайте ответвление от основной ветки (у вас `master`):

```
$ git checkout -b issue3 master
```

и работайте в этой ветке.

если зависит — делайте ответвление от `issue2`:

```
$ git checkout -b issue3 issue2
```

время от времени имеет смысл получать обновления веток:

```
$ git fetch
```

и посматривать, что там творится. например, в ветке `master`:

```
$ git log origin/master
```

и даже «подтягивать» оттуда изменения в текущую ветку `issue3`.

а чтобы (насколько возможно) сохранить линейность истории (с минимум коммитов слияния), «подтягивать» имеет смысл командой `rebase`, а внесённые коммиты в общее хранилище до поры не отправлять:

```
$ git rebase origin/master
```

Comment: Дело в том, что `issue 3` это продолжение `issue 2`. Просто у меня нету времени ждать, пока мой пулл-реквест заревьювают, и нужно начинать работать над `issue 3`. А затем как заревьювают, я солью `issue 2` в `master` создам `issue 3` и хочу как-то залить уже сюда, в `issue 3` свои наработки, которые у меня появились, пока я ждал код-ревью на `issue 2`. Если я сделаю так, как описал в вопросе - это будет верным путем?

Comment: не улавливаю смысла в создаании какой-то «временной» ветки. по-моему, это лишняя сущность, которая лишь усложнит картину.

Comment: Но ведь Вы же советуете в ответе, если `issue 3` зависит от `issue 2` сделать ответвление.

Comment: ну, более подходящего термина, чем «ответвление» я не знаю. а советов по созданию временных веток у меня в ответе нет.

Comment: Хорошо, вот я делаю ответвление от `issue 2`. Затем меня заревьювали, я `issue 2` слил в `master`. Создал `issue 3`, а как мне дальше слить изменения, которые в ответвлении от `issue 2` в моё, созданное ответвление от `master` - `issue 3`?

Comment: *Создал issue 3* — зачем создавать одну и ту же ветку второй раз? а, кажется, догадываюсь, где в ваших размышлениях «затык». ветка в программе git — это не набор изменений (как, например, в svn или hg), а **указатель** на коммит. ровно на один коммит.

Comment: я знаю про это. У меня проект должен состоять из 5ти issue. Вот и возник вопрос, что когда я создам от ветки `master` ветку `issue 3` как в неё потом слить изменения, из ответвленной от `issue 2`  ветки `issue 3 tmp`

Comment: Всё, с rebase получил то, что хотел!